# While loop condition with double and float

Tags: c

i have a simple task that says 'Write the value of y with the following formula for the range between xmin and xmax with the difference of dx.
The only problem i have is that when using while with float, such as in code i am going to provide, i am getting one less output of y than i should have.
For the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float x,xmin,xmax,dx,y;
    printf("Input the values of xmin xmax i dx");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&xmin,&xmax,&dx);
    x=xmin;
    while(x<=xmax) {
        y=(x*x-2*x-2)/(x*x+1);
        printf("%.3f   %.3f\n",x,y);
        x=x+dx;
    }
}
```

for the input of (-2 2 0.2) i get output only up to 1.8 (that's 20 outputs) and not up to 2.
But when i use double instead of float everything works just fine (Has 21 outputs).
Is there something connected to the while condition that i am not aware of?

Comment: Floating point rounding errors...

Comment: Have you checked what the specific values that `x` takes on in both situations?

Comment: Instead of `"%.3f"` for `x`, try `"%.12f"` both with `float` and `double`.

Comment: Instead of `while (x <= xmax)`, try `while (x <= xmax + epsilon)`, where epsilon is some very small value (and specifically, must be less than dx).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That makes sense. Float or double are an approximation rather an exact representation of Rational Numbers a/b:integers, b!=0. The closer you are to 1.000... the better the approximation but still an approximation.

A subset of rational numbers guaranteed to be exactly represented by floating point representation are rationals: 2^k, with k:integer [-126<= x <= 127 . Eg. const float dx = 0.25f; ~ 1/(2^2) would have worked fine.

> 0.2 is not represented as 0.2 rather as: 0.20000000298023223876953125
>   The next closest approximation to 0.2 is: 0.199999988079071044921875
>   https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

An alternative way to loop floats might be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float x,xmin,xmax,dx,y;
    printf("Input the values of xmin xmax i dx");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&xmin,&xmax,&dx);
    x=xmin;

    //expected cummulative error
    const float e = 0.7 * dx;

    do 
    {
        y=(x*x-2*x-2)/(x*x+1);
        printf("%.3f   %.3f\n",x,y);
        x=x+dx;
    }
    while(!(x > (xmax + e)));
}
```

The solution above appears to be working as expected but it would only do so for small number of iterations.

Comment: "The only numbers exactly represented are 2^k, with k:integer " -- disagree. You can, for example, exactly represent 3.0 as a `float`.